# libreoffice calc arithmetic inside number formatting?

Tags: formatting, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Is it possible to perform arithmetic inside a formatting declaration?  I want to display =1 as 1mg, =0.1 as 100 mcg, =0.0001 as 100ng, etc.

Comment: You want the same cell format setting to do all of those? Or are each of those individual settings?

Comment: All in one format.

Comment: Well you don't have a consistent scaling between them. 1 = 1mg, .1 = 100mg. You would need to probably have a seperate one for each, but see my answer on how to divide by 1000. Hope this helps. (This pretty much exhausts my excel knowledge, and had to look at an old sheet for the division via formatting)

Comment: 100mcg, not mg.  I want the largest unit-size that still allows a figure before the decimal point.  So this would require multiplication (by thousand) to turn the 0.1 (mg) into 100 (mcg)

Comment: mcg = μg? (I thought you mispelled mg) The SI prefix for micro is μ (Mu)

Comment: Yes meeting dumb character quota.

Comment: I'm aware of that, just never bothered learning the keyboard shortcut.  mcg is a valid notation.  In any case, this is getting off topic.

Comment: True enough, Check out the link and see if that will work. It doesn't use formatting, but looks to be modifiable for what you are wanting.

Answer (score 2):

For the milligram one, you can do:

```
0" mg"
```

For division, (by 1000) you can use:

```
#,##0.000,;-#,##0.000,
```

(Then just add a label to it.)

Edit:
After looking around on the web, I found something fairly similiar that allows scaling from Hz - GHz. It uses another cell and some IFs to format, but likely will be the best solution for what you are doing. (Afaik, excel format does not support macro-ing) 
The code to modify cell A1 is:

```
=IF(A1>=10^6,TEXT(A1/10^6,"0.0#")&" MHz",IF(A1>=10^3,TEXT(A1/10^3,"0.0#")&" KHz",TEXT(A1,"0.0#")&" Hz"))
```

(Referenced from: [Link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/excel-2010-display-of-si-units-is-this-possible/758313fb-59c3-41ee-9726-b50ae4a0cf37?auth=1))

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping the software would have the means, as it should, of properly separating presentation and content, but I should be able to adapt this in the particular scenario that I need it for.  This is more of a hack, though.

Comment: @RobF I apologize for it's "hacky" nature. I just sadly don't know any other way to do it. If you manage to figure it out, be sure to answer the question so others can benefit from it as well. Good luck.

Comment: There is currently no way to do this in the number formats. While ODF supports such number formats in theory I know no spreadsheet application that currently supports that part of ODF.